# Hybrid parameters vs. frequency

Tags: transistors, bjt, modeling, parameters

The question I need to solve is: how do the *h* parameters (hybrid) vary as a function of frequency?

In particular, I need to estimate the *Y* parameters (admitance parameters) for a 2N3904 transistor, but I only have the *h* parameters, as a function of the collector current, measured with a 1 kHz signal.

I need the *Y* parameters to model a circuit with this transistor, which operates at 10 Mhz. Is it possible to estimate the *Y* parameters @ 10 Mhz, from the *h* parameters @ 1 kHz?

I know that it is possible to convert from *h* parameters to *Y* parameters, but I don't know how the frequency variation affects it.

An alternative is to find a datasheet where the admittance parameters are specified for a range of frequencies, but I have searched without result.

Comment: Given Cob[coupling from col to base,  and Ftau on how beta rolls off, and C_eb, what could you do?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf You say calculate the admittances from the pi model?

Comment: Certainly the two capacitors easily become part of a more detailed model. Ftau, describing beta rolloff, I've often used in napkin scribbles but not as part of formal model.

Answer (score 0):

Z, Y, H, S parameters are "measured" values at a specific bias and frequency.

You can convert H to Y but the bias and frequency is the same.

So 1Khz H can only be converted to 1Khz Y.